# How to use rails-i18n on ActiveRecordError with association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, localization

I'm trying to translate https://github.com/lifo/docrails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb

In my controller file I have:

```
@book = Book.find(params[:id])

begin
  @book.destroy
rescue ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError => e
  flash[:error]= e.message # <<< Translate this message ?
end
```

This is the translation file I use : https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/th.rb

How do I write code for `translate "#{e.message}"`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your `en.yml` file

```
activerecord:
   book:
    error: 'book error: %{e}'
```

Then change the rescue block with the following

```
flash[:error] = t("book.error") % {:e => e.message}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue once before.

So there are two solutions;

---

a. Either you can flash the translated error yourself by manually specify the "code"

```
@book = Book.find(params[:id])

begin
  @book.destroy
rescue ActiveRecord::DeleteRestrictionError => e
  flash[:error]= I18n.t('en.activerecord.errors.messages.restrict_dependent_destroy')
end
```

---

b. Or you can use the gem `rails-i18n` which you are using anyway;

Fristly you need to config your `book` model:

```
has_many :children, dependent: :restrict_with_error
```

then you can just do

```
@book = Book.find(params[:id])

if @book.destroy
  # show success message
else
  flash[:error] = resource.errors.messages[:base].join(', ')
  # should include the translated error message if you are using rails-i18n
end
```

I assume you are using `:restrict_with_exception` instead of `:restrict_with_error`, just want to provide an alternative just in case.